# ApplicationContextProvider suddenly null

Tags: java, spring

For the past 2 weeks things have been going great in my application.  Last night I login remotely to work to find out that when I run my application my `ApplicationContextProvider` class no longer has knowledge of the Application Context.  I've run Maven clean & build in addition to rebooting my PC.  Can't seem to shake it...

```
public class ApplicationContextProvider implements ApplicationContextAware {
    private static ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    public static ApplicationContext getApplicationContext() {
        return applicationContext;
    }

    public void setApplicationContext (ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }
}
```

My Main class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    System.setProperty("java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format", "%4$s: %5$s%n");

    final HttpServer server = HttpServer.createSimpleServer(".", 80);

    WebappContext ctx = new WebappContext("ProductionQueue", "/");

    //enable annotation configuration
    ctx.addContextInitParameter("contextClass", "org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext");
    ctx.addContextInitParameter("contextConfigLocation", "com.production");

    //allow spring to do all of it's stuff
    ctx.addListener("org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener");

    ....
    ctx.deploy(server);

    server.start();

    //start the production process
    Production.init();

    System.in.read();
    server.stop();
```

My Production class:

```
public class Production {
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Production.class.getName());

    /* A list of active workflows */
    private static List<Workflow> workflowList = new ArrayList<Workflow>();

    private static ProductionService productionService;

    /**
     * Initialize the production line
     */
    public static void init() {
        logger.info("Initializing production workflows...");
        ApplicationContext context = ApplicationContextProvider.getApplicationContext(); //THIS IS NULL
        productionService = (ProductionService) context.getBean("productionService");
```

No configuration has been modified at all.  Within my config class I do have a bean for it...

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {
        "com.production"
})
@PropertySource(value= {
        "classpath:/application.properties",
        "classpath:/environment-${FETTER_ENVIRONMENT}.properties"
})
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.production.repository")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class Config {
    @Value("${db.url}")
    String PROPERTY_DATABASE_URL;
    @Value("${db.user}")
    String PROPERTY_DATABASE_USER;
    @Value("${db.password}")
    String PROPERTY_DATABASE_PASSWORD;

    @Value("${persistenceUnit.default}")
    String PROPERTY_DEFAULT_PERSISTENCE_UNIT;

    @Value("${hibernate.dialect}")
    String PROPERTY_HIBERNATE_DIALECT;
    @Value("${hibernate.format_sql}")
    String PROPERTY_HIBERNATE_FORMAT_SQL;
    @Value("${hibernate.show_sql}")
    String PROPERTY_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL;
    @Value("${entitymanager.packages.to.scan}")
    String PROPERTY_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN;

    @Bean
    public ApplicationContextProvider applicationContextProvider() {
        return new ApplicationContextProvider();
    }
```

Comment: _rebooting my PC_ That usually won't do anything. Do you have any kind of source versioning to check if something was modified?

Comment: Have you testet that the `setApplicationContext` method is invoked? I do not know if `@Bean
    public ApplicationContextProvider applicationContextProvider() {
        return new ApplicationContextProvider();
    }` would trigger that.

Comment: @Ralph - It is never invoked

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis - Yes.  No changes were made to the configuration of any kind or the `Main` class.  Changes were made to other classes, I'm still going through them to try to determine if any of these might have affected anything, but I can't imagine how they could have.

Comment: I strongly recommend to have autmatic tests that get executed with every checkin (for your next project). -- Now you have a good argument for it when you need to discuss with your boss about a continues integration server. ;-)

Comment: Is the constructor of `ApplicationContextProvider` invoked?

Comment: @Ralph - Constructor never gets invoked.  I just started writing tests this last iteration and am loving them.  I started to write a test for this ContextProvider which led me to this error (http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/java-lang-classformaterror-absent-code-attribute-in-method-that-is-not-native-or-abstract-in-class-file/) which I haven't fixed yet.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis - I reverted to my previous commit and it definitely works correctly.  That's good news... but dangit :-\

Comment: @Webnet Yay for investigations! Did you find what caused it? Some PostProcessor or something?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis - Well, I've written a lot of code since my previous commit that I don't want to lose.  The thing is... this Production.init() is the first method executed after Grizzly boots up.  So there's not a whole lot I could've "broken" before then when no changes were made to the Grizzly config

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there was a buried exception my logging was preventing me from getting access to.  Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say its mudsoup between the try to have it static and use it as a bean.

You creating a new instance of the `ApplicationContextProvider` as a spring bean. This is `ApplicationContextAware` and so gets the AC injected. But THEN you do not use said bean, you use its static getter to read the field, yet this, static thing never received the AC in the first place. You're never using your actual bean.

I'd say scratch that provider completly, and rely soley on the `ApplicationContextAware` interface, it does what you want, ie it was designed to do exactly that, why use a delegating bean?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if

```
@Bean
public ApplicationContextProvider applicationContextProvider() {
    return new ApplicationContextProvider();
}
```

the `ApplicationContextAware` interface.

Try to add `@Component` at `ApplicationContextProvider` class and then remove the `@Bean`. I hope that the ApplicationContextAware` interface is taken in account if this class is found by your normal component scan.

Comment: Thanks, this allowed me to remove the Bean definition as you said.